# Android Studio accessing Fragment method from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got really anoying problem with accessing methods in Fragment.

Error that I got

> Process: com.crelix.crelix, PID: 18913
>                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.crelix.crelix.ClickerFragment.refreshViews()' on a null object reference
>                                                                          at com.crelix.crelix.NavigationActivity.Refresh(NavigationActivity.java:530)
>                                                                          at com.crelix.crelix.NavigationActivity$1$1.run(NavigationActivity.java:84)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)

My Fragment Example:

```
    package com.crelix.crelix;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class ClickerFragment extends Fragment {

        public static ClickerFragment newInstance() {
            ClickerFragment fragment = new ClickerFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public ClickerFragment() {
    }

private TextView MoneyText;
private TextView MoneyPerTapTView;
private TextView BoxesText;
private TextView BoxesPerTapTView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

MainHolder Main = new MainHolder();

public void refreshViews(){
    MoneyText.setText("Money: " +Main.Money[0]);
    MoneyPerTapTView.setText("$ " + Main.Money[1] + " per tap");
    BoxesText.setText("Boxes: " + Main.Boxes[0] + "/100");
    BoxesPerTapTView.setText("Points " + Main.Boxes[1] + " per tap");
    progressBar.setProgress(Main.Boxes[0]);
}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clicker, container, false);
        MoneyText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyText);
        MoneyPerTapTView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyPerTapTView);
        BoxesText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesText);
        BoxesPerTapTView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesPerTapTView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

And I want to access it from MainActivity like:

```
 public void Refresh()
{
    ClickerFragment ClickerFragment = (ClickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ClickerFragment);
    ClickerFragment.refreshViews();
}
```

Here I add my Fragments

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_clicker) {
        fragment = new ClickerFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_upgrades) {
        fragment = new UpgradeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_warehouse) {
        fragment = new WarehouseFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_postservice) {
        fragment = new PostserviceFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shop) {
        fragment = new ShopFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_market) {
        fragment = new MarketFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_workshop) {
        fragment = new WorkshopFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_garage) {
        fragment = new GarageFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_museum) {
        fragment = new MuseumFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_collections) {
        fragment = new CollectionsFragment();
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The problem with this is it's not checking if the fragment is visible or the element have been created yet. Look at the lifecycle of a fragment for further clarification, but the gist of it is most likely onCreateView hasn't fired yet when you're trying to call refreshViews.

Comment: @Manza Edited. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `findFragmentById` if the fragment was statically embedded in the XML within an activity and given an `android:id`.

In your case, it looks like that the fragment was dynamically added at runtime within an activity. So you can lookup this fragment **by tag** by calling `findFragmentByTag` on the **FragmentManager**. In your `onNavigationItemSelected`, you need to change to this:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  String TAG = "";
  Fragment fragment = null;
  if (id == R.id.nav_clicker) {
    fragment = new ClickerFragment();
    TAG = "CLICKER_TAG";
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_upgrades) {
    fragment = new UpgradeFragment();
    TAG = "UPDATE_TAG";
  }
  // You need to add TAG to another fragment.
  ...

  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(). 
              replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, TAG).
              commit();
  ...
  return true;
}
```

Now you can lookup the fragment by tag:

```
ClickerFragment clickerFragment  = (ClickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                                    .findFragmentByTag("CLICKER_TAG");
// Now you have the fragment
// But remember to check if the fragment null
if(clickerFragment != null) {
  ClickerFragment.refreshViews();
}
```

Read more at [Creating and Using Fragments](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/creating-and-using-fragments).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `MainActivity` code with

```
ClickerFragment ClickerFragment = (ClickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `onNavigationItemSelected` for all your `Fragments` if necessary

```
Fragment fragment = null;
String tag = null;
if (id == R.id.nav_clicker) {
    fragment = new ClickerFragment();
    tag = "ClickerFragment";
}
...
if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //Add a tag parameter
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag).commit();
}
```

In your `Refresh` method do this

```
public void Refresh()
{
    ClickerFragment ClickerFragment = (ClickerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ClickerFragment");
    ClickerFragment.refreshViews();
}
```